# Matching weights

Tags: propensity-scores, matching

I am planning to apply propensity score matching with exact marching on two categorical variables and balancing on the rest of my covariates. Are the weights obtained from the matchit function related to balanced covariates or a combination of balanced covariates and exact matching?

Comment: The weights obtained from `matchit()` correspond to whatever form of matching you used. If the weights did not come from exact matching, what would be the point of exact matching?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Noah.